# Still software companies are using Css3 Gird Layout?

Tags: css, flexbox

Am trying to create a dashboard using HTML and CSS, whats my question is, is it good or bad if I use it for application in css3 grid layout?  Or which standard CSS code are using in the software industries

Thanks

```
.one {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  .two {
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
  }
  .three {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2 / 5;
  }
  .four {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 3;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS grid is supported by most modern browsers. See [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-grid) for specific details.
Although IE doesn't support it, Microsoft will stop support of the browser in August 2021, which means that from now on, all major browsers will support grid.

In case you really worry about users still using legacy browsers, you can still implement fallbacks, as presented in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3xvMKgtB-c).

Comment: i want to know about the application development companies are using css3 gird or common layout css like width float: left etc. please will you explain me ?

Comment: It's difficult to know for all companies, but I would expect a lot of them to use at least flexbox and most likely grid. float would probably not be used very much these days.

Comment: Thanks, Mate!

Where I can get a sample layout of css3 gird layout & flex box layout?

Comment: Would this do the trick? https://css-tricks.com/the-holy-grail-layout-with-css-grid/